# How can I solve string to DataFrame in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

if i get string data like sample, how can i convert string data to dataframe

```py
import pandas as pd

sample = "'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': [4, 5, 6], 'C': [7, 8, 9]"

df = pd.DataFrame({sample})

df.to_excel("output.xlsx", index=False)
```

result was 1 row but i want 3rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `eval`, but I do not recommend it.

```
In [2]: sample = "'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': [4, 5, 6], 'C': [7, 8, 9]"

In [3]: data = eval('{' + sample + '}')

In [4]: pd.DataFrame(data)
Out[4]:
   A  B  C
0  1  4  7
1  2  5  8
2  3  6  9
```

Comment: then what can I use instead of eval? could you give me a hint?

Comment: Ask the source for proper data format instead of Python literal representation. json, csv... anything will do. Then parse those using json, csv, or pandas. example in json: `{"A": [1, 2, 3], "B": [4, 5, 6], "C": [7, 8, 9]}`. If you cannot change that then `eval`, or a safer way as other comment `literal_eval`.

Answer (score 1):

Since the string represents a valid dictionary literal, you can make use of [Abstract Syntax Tree](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) (AST) module.

You will import ast module, use it to convert the 'sample' to dictionary object which can then be parse into a dataframe like so;-

```
import ast
import pandas as pd

sample = "'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': [4, 5, 6], 'C': [7, 8, 9]"
sample_dict = ast.literal_eval("{" + sample + "}")

df = pd.DataFrame(sample_dict)
df.to_excel("output.xlsx", index=False)

# Out put of df...
    A   B   C
0   1   4   7
1   2   5   8
2   3   6   9
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can implement `json.loads`

```
import pandas as pd
import json

sample = "'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': [4, 5, 6], 'C': [7, 8, 9]"

# Convert single quotes to double quotes
sample_dict = "{" + sample.replace("'", '"') + "}"

# Convert string to dictionary using json.loads
data_dict = json.loads(sample_dict)

df = pd.DataFrame(data_dict)
print(df)

# Output
   A  B  C
0  1  4  7
1  2  5  8
2  3  6  9
```